# CollectionView gets messed or terminates application when fastly updated

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, observablecollection, collectionview

I'm doing a live chat app and its "main container" is a CollectionView that binds to an ObservableCollection. It receives messages all the time and if it occurs in 1 or 2 seconds it works as expected but if someone send messages fastly, the collectionview is getting messed, some data doesn't appears until I manually scroll up/down the view. Sometimes even scrolling, shows the respective item's frame but empty. Also when I set `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"` in .XAML, it seems the things gets more messy and causes the app termination with this exception:

```
Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 99(offset:100).state:100 crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.CollectionViewRenderer{74c5a27 VFED..... ......ID 20,20-1420,1932 #8}, adapter:crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.GroupableItemsViewAdapter_2@ab0a24a, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@d28671f, context:android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@c8804e6
  at java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 99(offset:100).state:100 crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.CollectionViewRenderer{74c5a27 VFED..... ......ID 20,20-1420,1932 #8}, adapter:crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.GroupableItemsViewAdapter_2@ab0a24a, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@d28671f, context:android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@c8804e6
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5923)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
  at at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5044)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:635)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Cause of that, I'm scrolling the CollectionView using `MyCollectionView.ScrollTo(MyObservableCollection.Count - 1, position: ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, animate: false);` instead of  `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"`

I can solve all this mess by adding a sleep timer of 2 seconds but it wouldn't be a good solution since the app is supposed to be a live chat. Does someone knows how can I solve that?

Comment: Make sure you do not close when you receive zero bytes.  I is a valid condition to receive zero bytes so make sure you do not close when you get zero bytes.  This is a common mistake.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10298

Comment: @jdweng sorry, I didn't understand. Do not close what?

Comment: @Jason thanks, will have a look on this right now.